# Weierstrass factorization/proving existence of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers without an accumulation point. Let $c_n$ be an arbitrary sequence of complex numbers. Prove that, there is an entire function f, such that $f(a_n)=c_n$.

So the Weierstrass factorization ensures the existence of a holomorphic function, such that $f(a_n)=0$, so $c_n=0$, $\forall n$, we would be finished. But how can I proceed when $c_n \neq 0 \forall n$?

Comment: Use also [Mittag-Leffler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem). If you get an entire function with zeros at each of those points and another with poles of order one at each and with residues $c_n$, their product interpolates those values.

Comment: Another way can be to the same as in Lagrange interpolation or the Chinese Remainder Theorem: You get functions $f_n$ that are zero at all exactly all those points, except $a_n$. By multiplying by $c_n/f_n(a_n)$ you can assume that $f_n(a_n)=c_n$. Then you can "add" the $f_n$, except that in order to get convergence we should scale them, say by $2^{-n}$. So, instead of assuming that $f_n(a_n)=c_n$, let's assume that $f_n(a_n)=2^nc_n$. Then we sum $f=\sum_n2^{-n}f_n$.

Comment: @owl thank you very much for the suggestions, could you explain the first case more? So ML gives us the existence of a meromorphic function with poles at $a_n$ and with residues $c_n$. But I do not yet fully get  the multiplication part

Comment: Ah, we should choose the residues better. Take $h(z)$ to have zeros of order $1$ (choosing the order is also important) exactly at the sequence $a_n$. So, near each $a_n$ we have $h(z)=(z-a_n)(h'(a_n)+H(z))$, where $h'(a_n)\neq0$, $H$ is entire and $H(a_n)=0$. Now, from ML we get $g(z)$ with poles of order $1$ at each $a_n$ and residue $c_n/h'(a_n)$. So, near $a_n$ we have $g(z)=\frac{c_n/h'(a_n)}{z-a_n}+G(z)$, where $G$ is regular near $a_n$. This way when we multiply $f(z)=h(z)g(z)$ we get $f(z)=(z-a_n)(h'(a_n)+H(z))(\frac{c_n/h'(a_n)}{z-a_n}+G(z))=c_n+F(z)$, where $F$ is regular near $a_n$

Comment: anything unclear?

Comment: @owl: thank you very much for this lengthy and detailed comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wlog assume that $|a_n|$ is increasing. The $a_n$ are distinct. Set $f_1(z)=c_1$ and

$$f_k(z)= f_{k-1}(z)+ (c_k-f_{k-1}(a_k))(z/a_k)^{e_k} \prod_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{z-a_n}{a_k-a_n}$$

To ensure that $\lim_{k\to \infty}f_k$ converges locally uniformly, take $e_k$ large enough so that $$\sup_{|z|<|a_k|-1}|(c_k-f_{k-1}(a_k))(z/a_k)^{e_k} \prod_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{z-a_n}{a_k-a_n}|<2^{-k}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer